# belongsToMany with multiple tables (design suggestion)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 tables in my laravel/vue project:

- Movies
- Series
- Anime
- Actors
- Actors relationship

Actors' table belongs to Movies, Series, Anime and this many-to-many relationship is registered in the `actors_relationship`.

I'm able to create a many-to-many relationship in the `Actor.php` model using the following code:

```
public function movies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(MovieModel::class, "actors_relationship", 'actor_id', 'media_id')->wherePivot("media_type", AdminHelper::TYPE_MOVIES['value'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Using this code I'm getting the records with the included actor id and has a specific int as a `media_type`.

Until this point, I have no problem. My problem is getting the count of all of these relationships. e.g. getting the count of movies, series, anime and sorting it desc/asc

**Solutions:**

1. Retrieving the relationship actors' count from movies, series, anime and register it in a custom `attribute`. The sorting will be on the client-end.
2. Doing a hard code check on the server-side for the sorting, then checking if the sort is by `total_count`, if yes, then get the collection first and after the `->get()` command, try sorting by the custom `attribute`.

I would like to follow the best practice regarding this issue. Is there a way to get the count of all relationships and sort by it?

A client-side solution would cause more work because this project will be for Android and Web and therefore will require various modifications in both fields.

Furthermore, I would normally do `->with('movies')` and then sort the automatically created field `movies_count`. I would like to have a similar approach.

**Tables:**

`actors`:

```
id actor_title
```

`movies`:

```
id movie_title
```

`series`:

```
id series_title
```

`anime`:

```
id anime_title
```

`actors_relationship`:

```
id actor_id media_id media_type
```

EDIT:

I'm looking for the best advice to implement a total count of `movies`, `series` and `anime`. This means that I would like the total count of these 3 relations in one field. I could use a custom attribute, but then I will need to sort that using PHP/client-side instead of doing it in the SQL query in Eloquent.

This means that I'm looking for the best way that follows the best practices.
The `total_count` will sum up the total of those aforementioned relations. I would like to sort by this new `total_count`.

Comment: Why don't you store movies, series and anime in a single table with a type column?

Comment: I did, but I don't really think it's the best possible solution. Because then, I will need to insert the record in two tables, which are the `generic_table` which has all of these items & type and the type table, e.g. `series`, `anime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good case for a MorphToMany https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

```
    class Actor

    public function movies()
        {
            return $this->morphedByMany(MovieModel::class,'media',"actors_relationship");
        }

/// Add a the count to the query 

    public function scopeWithRelationsCount($q)
    {
        /// this is needed to so we keep the select of all the table columns too
        if(!$q->getQuery()->columns){
            $q->select($this->getTable().'.*');
        }

        return $q->selectSub(

                ActorRelationship::selectRaw('count(*)')->whereColumn('actor_id', 'actors.id'),

                'relations_count' /// the alias we are using could be anything  
            )
    }
```

Then you if you want the total number of series, movies and and anime for each actor ordered by most you can  use.
`Actor::withRelationsCount()->orderBy('relations')->get()`

There are some macros that make this look a little nicer. Take a look at https://github.com/reinink/advanced-eloquent.

Comment: This's a good approach. But what about the total count of all items? Is it possible with `morphedByMany`? e.g. doing a generic `references` that doesn't care for the returned model, instead cares for the count and only used for stats. Because I would be using the `movies()` and `series()` If I would want to read the data and render it.

Comment: So you want to be able to do something like Actor::orderBy('movies_count')->get()? Will Actor::withCount('movies')->orderBy('movies_count')->get() not work?

Comment: No, I want to order by the references as a whole. This means that I do NOT know if the actor has movies or series, therefore, I want to sortBy the count of both series & movies. I could make a custom attribute which has the total count of these relations. As a result, I will have to `get()` the items then `sort` because this custom attribute isn't a database field. I don't know if this is anti-practice.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Could you provide an example of how it would be using the macros?

Comment: It explains in this article probably better than I can. https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries

Comment: I still have a question. Would this be efficient while having 1K+ records in each table?

Comment: That's the idea anyways. I used this personally on tables with over 50k rows and it was the most efficient solution I found. It was faster and more memory efficient than eager loading the whole model.